# Bones are rotated wrong direction on play mode

Tags: unity, animation, blender, skeletal-animation, rigging

I made animations from Blender and exported as FBX.

However in Unity, default pose seems fine in edit mode.

[image]

But in play mode, spine bones are rotated wrong direction:
[image]

It's Humanoid type and each bones are set correctly without any error. There's nothing make change to those bones but why it has wrong rotation in play mode?

What am I missing? What should I check about this?

Any advice will very appreciate it.

Comment: weird.  check to see if your transform is being inverted.  Look for -1 on the scale.

Comment: You may want to try applying the transformation in Blender first, before exporting - should be something like "Select all Bones (Armature)", "Control+A" "Select Rotation".